# How to get the value of related content of a task list in sharepoint 2013 using Javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm attempting to get the value of the Related Content field in SharePoint 2013. I'm using the internal name of WorkflowLink and getting [object Object] back as the result. How can I pull back the URL that is stored in this column?

```
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();      
while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

    listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
        '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
        '\nWorkflowLink: ' + oListItem.get_item('WorkflowLink');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

oListItem.get_item('WorkflowLink').get_url() will return the URL of this field.